# Android Custom Event Listener

Tags: java, andengine

I'm using AndEngine and Box2d in android application.
How to make my object "Player" to throw an event and the "GameScene" subscribes to it?

```
public class Player {

  @Override
  public void Collision(GameObject object) {
    if(object instanceof Coin) {
        //throws an event here
    }
  }
}

public class GameScene {
  private Player player = new Player();
  //catch the event here
```

}

Answer (score 9):

You should use `interface`s.

Make an interface something like:

```
public interface Something
{
  void doSomething(GameObject object);
}
```

Where `doSomething` is the method which will be called (In this case could be `objectCollision`) same for interface name (`ObjectCollider`(?)).

then let GameScene implement it

```
public class GameScene implements Something
```

and implement the method.

In the Player class, add a listener to this:

```
public class Player {
 private Something listener;
```

And in the constructor ask for the listener:

```
public Player(Something listener) { this.listener = listener; }
```

Then to invoke it, just use

```
listener.doSomething(object);
```

Example:

```
public void Collision(GameObject object) {
   if(object instanceof Coin) {
     //throws an event here
     listener.doSomething(object);
   }
}
```

To create the Player object with this constructor you just need to do:

```
Player player = new Player(this); // if you implement the method in the class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android life cycle](https://github.com/Ilya-Gazman/android_life_cycle) for that.

Create a signal

```
interface IGameSignal{
    void gameHandler();
}

class GameSignal extends Signal<IGameSignal> implements IGameSignal{

    void gameHandler(){
        dispatch();    
    }
}
```

Than register to it in GameCence or anywhere else you want, there could be many listeners to same `Signal`.

```
class GameScene implements IGameSignal{
    GameSignal gameSignal = Factory.inject(GameSignal.class);

    void init() {
        newsUpdateSignal.addListener(this);        
    }

    public void gameHandler(){

    }
}
```

And dispatch the signal when you need, from where ever you need.

```
Class A{
    GameSignal gameSignal = Factory.inject(GameSignal.class);

    void execute(){
        // dispatch the signal, the callback will be invoked on the same thread
        gameSignal.gameHandler();
    }        
}
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of android life cycle.*