# Passing Data from Dialog box to activity

Tags: android

I am having the problem with passing data from `DialogBox` to an `Activity`.my main activity
has one `Button` when the button is clicked it opens a dialog window.The `Dialog window` has
`EditText` and two `Buttons`.When the add button is clicked it needs to pass the `EditText` data to main activity.This is the scenario.Here are my codes.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button showdialog;
    CustomDialog cdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showdialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        showdialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cdd=new CustomDialog(MainActivity.this);
                cdd.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void getinfo() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cdd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

CustomDialog.java

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{

    Activity c;
    Button add,cancel;
    EditText name;
    MainActivity act;

    public CustomDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c=a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        act = new MainActivity();
        Intent myintent=new Intent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2:
                act.getinfo();
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

If i run this code `MainActivity Leaked` error comes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling method from class which extend `Activity` by creating object in non-activity class you should create custom event listener using `interface` which trigger event when `onClick` happen in `Dialog`.

[Android Custom Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881661/android-custom-event-listener)

Comment: @Ranjith: sure try this let me know if you have issue after that

Comment: could you please give some ideas to create custom event listener using interface based on my problem

Comment: @Ranjith: i have already provided you an post link but if still facing issue then post your updated code what you have tried

Comment: hi i updated the code with interface listener.But there is a problem in that.My CustomDialog class constructor has 2 parameters one is Activity and the Listener of interface.how i initialize constructor in mainactivity

Comment: @Ranjith: no need to pass two parameter in CustomDialog class constructor just use one. do it as     public CustomDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c=a;
        interface_listener=(interface_Listener_Name)a;
    }

Comment: @Ranjith: means just cast `a` to Listener