# Passing String values from custom dialog to another activity

Tags: android, csv, android-alertdialog, gettext, getter

A custom dialog is being used to take in user input, and then these values are being passed to another activity using `getter` methods.

But when I pass the values to a method that outputs the string values to a `CSV` file, `shipName`, `analystName` etc the values appear as empty in the file like this, `" "` although I have entered the values in the dialog.

I debugged the problem by watching the  String values in the debug menu's expression window, `shipName` and `analystName` but the values never update in the expression window.

I gather from this that the method i which the input is being passed over is not correct.

Does anyone know why the values being output are empty?

This the dialog class being used:

```
package ie.gmi.computing;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.renderscript.Sampler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyMessageDialog {

    private Context context;
    private EditText shipText, scientistNameText , scientistEmailText , volumeText , colourText ;

    private String shipString, scientistNameString , scientistEmailString , volumeString , colourString ;



    public AlertDialog displayMessage(Context context, String title, String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
        builder.setView(v);
        shipText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.shipNameEditText);
        scientistNameText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.scientistEditText);
        scientistEmailText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        volumeText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.volumeEditText);
        colourText  = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.colourEditText);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog= builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        Button tb = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        tb.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener(dialog));

        return dialog;
    }


    //getter/setters to allow access to string values
    //in SearchResult class
    public EditText getShipText() {
        return shipText;
    }



    public void setShipText(EditText shipText) {
        this.shipText = shipText;
    }



    public EditText getScientistNameText() {
        return scientistNameText;
    }



    public void setScientistNameText(EditText scientistNameText) {
        this.scientistNameText = scientistNameText;
    }



    public EditText getScientistEmailText() {
        return scientistEmailText;
    }


    public void setScientistEmailText(EditText scientistEmailText) {
        this.scientistEmailText = scientistEmailText;
    }



    public String getShipString() {
        return shipString;
    }


    public void setShipString(String shipString) {
        this.shipString = shipString;
    }


    public String getScientistNameString() {
        return scientistNameString;
    }


    public void setScientistNameString(String scientistNameString) {
        this.scientistNameString = scientistNameString;
    }


    public String getScientistEmailString() {
        return scientistEmailString;
    }


    public void setScientistEmailString(String scientistEmailString) {
        this.scientistEmailString = scientistEmailString;
    }


    public String getVolumeString() {
        return volumeString;
    }


    public void setVolumeString(String volumeString) {
        this.volumeString = volumeString;
    }


    public String getColourString() {
        return colourString;
    }


    public void setColourString(String colourString) {
        this.colourString = colourString;
    }


    public EditText getVolumeText() {
        return volumeText;
    }



    public void setVolumeText(EditText volumeText) {
        this.volumeText = volumeText;
    }



    public EditText getColourText() {
        return colourText;
    }



    public void setColourText(EditText colourText) {
        this.colourText = colourText;
    }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private final Dialog dialog;
        public CustomListener(Dialog dialog) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(shipText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !shipText.getText().toString().equals(null)){
                shipText.setError("The Field is required");

            }else if(scientistNameText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !scientistNameText.getText().toString().equals(null)){
                scientistNameText.setError("The Field is required");
            }else if(scientistEmailText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !scientistEmailText.getText().toString().equals(null)){
                scientistEmailText.setError("The Field is required");
            }else if(volumeText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !volumeText.getText().toString().equals(null)){
                volumeText.setError("The Field is required");
            }else if(colourText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !colourText.getText().toString().equals(null)){
                colourText.setError("The Field is required");
            }else{
                shipText.setError(null);
                scientistNameText.setError(null);
                scientistEmailText.setError(null);
                volumeText.setError(null);
                colourText.setError(null);


                shipString = shipText.getText().toString();
                scientistNameString = scientistNameText.getText().toString();
                scientistEmailString = scientistEmailText.getText().toString();
                volumeString = volumeText.getText().toString();
                colourString = colourText.getText().toString();


                Toast.makeText(dialog.getContext(), "The Values you get from : " +
                        "\n Ship name value: " + shipText.getText().toString() +
                        "\n Scientist name value: " + scientistNameText.getText().toString() +
                        "\n email value: " + scientistEmailText.getText().toString() +
                        "\n sample volume value: " + volumeText.getText().toString() +
                        "\n sample colour value: " + colourText.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm retrieving the values in my SearchResult class, when i select the settings button:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:

            MyMessageDialog dialog =new MyMessageDialog(); 
            dialog.displayMessage(SearchResult.this, "Sample Info", "Required");



            // store / use the values here
            shipName = dialog.getShipString();
            analystName = dialog.getScientistNameString();
            analystEmail = dialog.getScientistEmailString();
            sampleVolume = dialog.getVolumeString();
            sampleColour = dialog.getColourString();
            longitudeValue = String.valueOf(lng);
            latitudeValue = String.valueOf(lat);
            sampleMaterial = message;

            return true;

        default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dialog showing is asynchronous; that is, code execution in `onOptionsItemSelected()` does not pause after the call to `dialog.displayMessage()`, so the getters are returning the initial values for those fields, which is null in all cases. You should create an interface that the Activity implements to receive a callback after those fields are set in the `onClick()` method of your `CustomListener`, and update the Activity's variables then.

In the dialog class, we create an interface. For example:

```
public class MyMessageDialog {
    public interface DialogCallback {
        public void onValuesSet();
    }
    ...
}
```

Be sure to save a reference to the Context:

```
public AlertDialog displayMessage(Context context, String title, String message){
    this.context = context;
    ...
}
```

And at the end of the `onClick()` method, after the fields' values are set:

```
((DialogCallback) context).onValuesSet();
```

The Activity needs to implement the interface we created, the dialog should be a class member, and the fields will be set in the interface's callback method:

```
public class SearchResult extends Activity 
    implements MyMessageDialog.DialogCallback {
    ...
    MyMessageDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onValuesSet()
    {
        shipName = dialog.getShipString();
        analystName = dialog.getScientistNameString();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: M, could you show a code example of this code be implemented?

Comment: @BrianJ Sure thing. It'll take me a second, though; I'm on a phone at the moment.

Comment: I added the above solution to my project but I get a null pointer exception at this line when "ok" is clicked,         `dialog.displayMessage(SearchResult.this, "Sample Info", "Required");` I may have not implemented your solution correctly..this is how I implemented the code into both classes:
http://hastebin.com/uzirotijiv.avrasm
http://hastebin.com/ugirunukod.avrasm

Do you have any idea as to where I went wrong with the solution?
`

Comment: @BrianJ You need to save a reference to the Context in the `displayMessage()` method: `this.context = context;`

Comment: Will this not cause a conflict with the line arleady in the method, `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);` .I have just added this line you suggested and will test, thanks

Comment: @BrianJ Nope. In that method, `context` - as opposed to `this.context` - will still refer to the parameter variable, but it doesn't really matter, as they'll both refer to the same object (i.e., after the assignment).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why the values being output are empty?

Because all statements from getting data from dialog class is executing after `dialog.displayMessage` on menu option section.

> How to get data from `MyMessageDialog` on `Ok` button click ?

**1.** Instead of getting `EditText` from MyMessageDialog change all getter/setter method return type to String..

**2.** Create a event Listener using `interface` for getting event of Alert close on `Ok` button click in Activity. you can create event listener as:

[Android Custom Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881661/android-custom-event-listener)

**3.** call all setter method on `Ok` button click of Alert. after calling all setter method call event listener method to execute event in Activity after Alert finish.:

```
      @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             setShipText(shipText.getText().toString());
             setScientistNameText(shipText.getText().toString());
             ....
             //..close alert and call event listener method
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getters don't seem to actually call the `getText()` method on each EditText view. Modify them do that they do (e.g., `scientistNameText.getText()`).

PS And, yes, Mike M may indeed write about asyncronicity contributing to the problem. Another approach around that would be to add something like this to the code for each EditText view:

```
myEditTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Set the variable here that you call in your getter. Use `getText()` to get the string (e.g., myGetterVariable = myEditTextView.getText().


        }
    }
```