# How to pass selected item from ListFragment to previous Fragment after calling popBackStack()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have prepared a very simple test case with 1 activity and 2 fragments for my question:

- [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q15/MyList/src/de/afarber/mylist/MainActivity.java) (stores selected item in shared preferences)
- [MyMainFragment.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q15/MyList/src/de/afarber/mylist/MyMainFragment.java) (displays a text view and a "select" button)
- [MyListFragment.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q15/MyList/src/de/afarber/mylist/MyListFragment.java) (displays a list of items)

[image: screenshot]

Initially MainActivity displays MyMainFragment.

When user touches "Select item..." button, MainActivity displays MyListFragment with:

```
public void selectedButtonClicked() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    int index = prefs.getInt(INDEX, -1);
    Fragment fragment = MyListFragment.newInstance(index);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .replace(R.id.root, fragment, LIST)
        .commit();
}
```

After user touches one of the items in the list, MainActivity stores the selected item position in shared preferences and calls `popBackStack()` to display the MyMainFragment again:

```
public void itemSelected(int index) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(INDEX, index);
    editor.commit();
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    // How to show the index in mSelectedTextView?
}
```

I.e. the MainActivity in my app does all the "heavy work": it displays 1 of 2 fragments and keeps the user data in shared preferences.

My question is: how to display the selected item (the "Item 07" in the above screenshot) in the `mSelectedTextView` of the MyMainFragment?

I'm looking for a way to do it properly, without any hacks (for example fragments shouldn't touch shared preferences).

**UPDATE:** I've tried the suggestion by corsair992 (thanks!)

```
public void itemSelected(int index) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(INDEX, index);
    editor.commit();
    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    MyMainFragment f = (MyMainFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.root);
    // call a method in MyMainFragment to update mSelectedTextView
    f.setText("Selected index: " + index);
}
```

but it only works, when user touches an item in MyListFragment. It does not however work, when user returns to MyMainFragment by touching Back button.

Comment: See following post for [Android Custom Event Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881661/android-custom-event-listener) using Custom event Fragment will get update from another Fragment

Comment: pass selected item from Fragment2 to Activity, and then from Activity to Fragment1

Comment: Yes, my question is how to do the 2nd part: "pass selected item from Activity to Fragment1" (where Fragment1 is restored from Back stack)

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: Just like you passed it from Fragment2 to Activity? Replace `popBackStack()` with `popBackStackImmediate()` and use `findFragmentById()` to retrieve the `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks @corsair992, I have updated my question: unfortunately `popBackStackImmediate()` does not help, when user returns to MyMainFragment by touching the Back button on the device.

Comment: Do you need to communicate with the main `Fragment` even when the user presses the back button without selecting any item? In that case you'll need to add a `OnBackStackChangedListener` to listen to that event.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening (or if OnBackStackChangedListener is applicable here), but when I touch Back button in MyListFragment, then I see "Nothing selected" in MyMainFragment (even if I had "Selected index: 3" before).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: You need to save the selected item as part of the main Fragment's state, as it gets destroyed and recreated when moved in and out of the back stack.

Comment: But how to save - without using the shared preferences? Just into a private field of MyMainFragment - wouldn't it be destroyed sometimes?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: Use the `onSaveInstanceState()` callback to save your state.

Comment: I thought this issue had been solved.. is there some issue remaining that hasn't been addressed?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I am looking for a definitive answer, which could always apply, when I have a ListFragment. Right now it's just pieces:  popBackStackImmediate(), OnBackStackChangedListener, onSaveInstanceState(). I am looking for a complete solution.

Comment: Combining these should result in a definitive answer :) (You shouldn't need to use the `OnBackStackChangedListener` though). The alternatives are to get the data directly from the `SharedPreferences` (which is a kind of static global state), or the `Activity`.

Comment: Maybe there is a nicer way with custom events...

Comment: Well, if you wish to use an event bus, you can do that too: http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: It looks like fragments that are removed in a transaction that is added to the back stack are still retained by the manager, so you should be able to set the main fragment as the target of the second fragment using the `setTargetFragment()` method and enable direct interaction between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you already have a reasonable first part to the answer (suggestion by corsair992 - pass the value from the item selected) the second part is how do you handle the back key.

There are a few ways of doing that (listening to the back stack etc.) but the one I have used most fequently is:

declare a back key listener interface:

```
public interface BackKeyListener {
   boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

in your main activity add the following:

```
import BackKeyListener;
void onBackKeyPressed() {
   boolean backKeyHandled = false;
   Fragment activeFragment = getActiveFragment();
   if (activeFragment instanceof BackKeyListener) {
      backKeyHandled = ((BackKeyListener) activeFragment).onBackKeyPressed();
   }
   if (!handled) {
      // If should process back key normally, pass to super..
      super.onBackKeyPressed();
   }
}

Fragment getActiveFragment() {
   // I'm assuming you place all your fragments here, if not..
   // alter to suit
   return getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.root);
}
```

in MyListFragment add the following:

```
import BackKeyListener;

class MyListFragment extends Fragment(orsomething) implements BackKeyListener

public boolean onBackPressed() {
  // User pressed back, select default item..
  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).itemSelected(selectedItem);

  // In this case, prevent normal back processing or
  // you might get a double backstack pop.
  return true;
}
```

Using an interface on the fragment allows you to "not care" what the active fragment is.
If it implements the BackKeyListener, the MainActivity will call it when the back key is pressed.
This gives you the option of passing a value back to the activity.

Comment: sometimes fragment can be detached before onBackPressed() callback of the Activity.

Comment: A valid point. It always pays to do null pointer checks when using fragment or activity references. (findFragment/getActivity etc.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you **can** use `SharedPrefences` inside UI thread, i.e. inside fragments. This common misconception takes root from the time when there was only `commit()` method. Now we have `apply()` working asynchronously and `get*()` using cached data.

Second, the simplest way to solve your problem, without juggling with SDK, will be to notify Activity of items selection in your second fragment (for example, inside your fragment: `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSelectedItem(itemId);`) and get this value on your first fragment's `onResume()` (for example, `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSelectedItem();`). Of course you should check this value for null in case nothing was selected.

Answer (score 1):

Is your first fragment still kept in memory when this happens? I assume so. This means you could use a [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). Just make MyMainFragment implement the interface and then use the `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to monitor for changes. Don't forget to unregister, though!

An even better idea might be to register your activity as the listener and make it pass that data to MyMainFragment when it displays it again.

Comment: "make the Activity pass that data to MyMainFragment" - that is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a tag to MyMainFragment, suppose it will be MY_MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG.
Add this code to your `itemSelected` method:

```
Fragment myMainFragment = getFragmentManger.findFragmentByTag("MY_MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG");
if (null != myMainFragment) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    myMainFragment.getArguments().putInt("selectedItem", index);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Then in your MyMainFragment override onViewStateRestored() method:

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    mSelectedTextView.setText(String.valueOf(getArguments.getInt("selectedItem")));
}
```

Probably you will need some additional checks if `null != getArguments()` and set apropriate value to a `TextView`.

Comment: Arguments can only be set on fragments when they haven't been initialized, and in this case the fragment is completely managed so you won't even get a reference to it until the manager pops it from the back stack.

Comment: @corsair992, You are wrong because i use this on production and everything works fine.

Comment: OK, your edited code might work, but it can only work if the `Fragment` hasn't been _removed_ from the `FragmentManager`, just detached. I'm guessing that's how you have implemented it in your production code.

Comment: @corsair992, just replacing like Alexander in his question.

Comment: The replace transaction causes the previous `Fragment` to be removed from the `FragmentManager`, and popping the back stack causes a new instance of it to be created, so I can't see how you can interact with the `Fragment` instance in that case before popping the back stack.

Comment: @corsair992, no. You are wrong. Replace never removes a Fragment from FragmentManager.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) of the `replace()` method in `FragmentTransaction`: "Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling `remove(Fragment)` for all currently added fragments that were added with the same `containerViewId` and then `add(int, Fragment, String)` with the same arguments given here."

Comment: Still nothing is told about removing fragments from a FragmentManager. From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace): When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped (not destroyed). If the user navigates back to restore the fragment, it restarts. If you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then the fragment is destroyed when removed or replaced.

Comment: OK, it seems you are correct. Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use setTargetFragment/getTargetFragment approach. With this approach 
you can use just your Fragments without the Activity and SharedPreferences help. 
In your MyMainFragment, when the user click the button
"Select item..." you can use your callback selectedButtonClicked() as :

```
public void selectedButtonClicked() {

Fragment fragment = MyListFragment.newInstance(index);

//Set the TargetFragment

fragment.setTargetFragment(MyMainFragment.this, MyListFragment.REQUESTCODE)

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .replace(R.id.root, fragment, LIST)
    .commit();
 }
```

You have to define  the callback onActivityResult of the MainFragment:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if(requestCode == MyListFragment.REQUESTCODE){
         f.setText("Selected index: " + intent.getInt("INDEX");
    }
}
```

In the MyListFragment once the user selects an item, you can call your callback itemSelected()

```
public void itemSelected(int index) {

Intent i = new Intent();    
i.putExtraInt("INDEX",index);
getTargetFragment.onActivityResult(MyListFragment.REQUESTCODE,Context.Result_OK,i);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

}
```