# Android working with Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-edittext

I am not quite sure what route to take but I have a PageViewer tab and each tab are fragments, those fragments contain content. In one tab which is ToDo, when the user clicks add button a new intent will open. My question is I dont want to open an activity that will defeat the overall purpose of using fragments, How can I open a new UI for users to fill in and add their ToDo's once theyre finish that fragment closes and goes back to ToDo tab to display his ToDo.

I am sorry if it is in the wrong section. I am new to fragments and it takes me time to understand the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to open a new UI with intent, especially when there's like "master-detail" flow. Building an application with the only 1 Activity and 100500 Fragments is a very bad architectural choice.

If you, however, still want to use transactions, you can do like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new ToDoInputFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("someString", someString);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), fragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

After user finished to enter his ToDos, if u want to refresh the ToDo list - you have to send result. You can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168342/how-to-pass-selected-item-from-listfragment-to-previous-fragment-after-calling-p/28215116#28215116) for how to achieve this, or use accepted answer - which i don't recommend to.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: @Jack, I would recommend using Intent to startActivityForResult and setResult for calling Activity.

Comment: I have MainActivity which extends FragmentActivity and thats how I add my tabs, how can I implement this can you give an example? Would a DialogFragment be idle?

Comment: @Jack, do like you do in your question - launch intent for new activity

Answer (score 0):

I would probably take the following approach in your place.

1. Put my ViewPager inside its own fragment.
2. Add that fragment to the main Activity.
3. Implement a new Fragment for the Todo view.
4. To open the Todo view replace the Fragment inside the main Activity with the new Todo Fragment.
5. Inside the OnBackPressed method of your main Activity pop the backstack to remove the Todo Fragment.

This is just one approach and it may not suit your needs but it can at least give you an idea of some of the possible concepts.