# Progress dialog box not showing in global AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

This is my MainActivity... i put one button, in button onclick i call asyncTask

```
package com.example.asnytaskpro;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AsyncMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button button ; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_async);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_async, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.err.println("1");
    try {
        new AllPrinterClass(AsyncMainActivity.this, "123456789123456789", "123").execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    };
}

}
```

This is My AsyncTaskClass

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AllPrinterClass extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>{

public static String ServerData = "";
private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
private Context context;
String TransNo = "" ,IMEINo = "";

int iRetValue = 0;

String  CurrentDate = null, CurrentTime= null;
SimpleDateFormat df,tf;


public AllPrinterClass(Context context1, String imeiNo,String transno2) 
{
        this.context        = context1;
        this.IMEINo         = imeiNo;
        this.TransNo        = transno2;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
        CurrentDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        tf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        CurrentTime = tf.format(c.getTime());

        System.err.println(CurrentDate);
        System.err.println(CurrentTime);


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    this.prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    this.prgDialog.setMessage("Place your finger on FPS ...");
    this.prgDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    this.prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.prgDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

//////////////////Doing my Code///////////////////

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.err.println("i :-" + i);
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return iRetValue;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    prgDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

This code working for me but my ProgressDialog not showing(May be run background).

In i remove prgDialog.dismiss(); in onPostExecute() Method then my dialog showing after doInBackground() Method.

I want dialog show in onPreExecute() Method and dismiss in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: write  super.onPreExecute(); on top and then define the progress dialog.

Comment: i did that....Not Working help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
...execute().get();
```

Calling get method will block main ui Thread until `doInBackground` execution not completed. that's why `ProgressDialog` is not showing.

Use only `execute()` method to start `AsyncTask` which show Progress Dialog during `doInBackground`  method execution:

```
    new AllPrinterClass(AsyncMainActivity.this,
                     "123456789123456789", "123").execute();
```

Comment: Now its working but i want some return value like Integer RetuenIntValue = new AllPrinterClass(AsyncMainActivity.this,  "123456789123456789", "123").execute().get(); thats why am use get(). now how can i get return???

Comment: @AnujZunjarrao: Not possible ro return value. but you can use `onPostExecute` method for updating UI elements. or you can also create a [Android Custom Event Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881661/android-custom-event-listener) to trigger event in AsyncMainActivity when `onPostExecute` method called

Comment: @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
 //this is where you will get the integer u need
}

Comment: @SachinRao: OP want to get value in `AsyncMainActivity` Activity

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: ooh!, then he will need to write a callback method, i guess

Comment: this may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119305/android-how-to-run-asynctask-from-different-class-file

Comment: ya may be i will go with global variable for return values..... but tell me one think how can i w8 async task completed.... in onclick button i want close AsyncMainActivity is i get success value...