# unresolved onOptionsItemSelected android

Tags: android, view

I'm getting an:

```
Cannot resolved method "onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem(View)"
```

when I try to return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);`

Here is what I have:

```
public class customView extends View {
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_undo:
                    lines.remove(lines.size()-1);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? When I remove that line then I get

```
Method does not override method from its superclass
```

error

Comment: `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` should come out of switch & add `break` after default.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot resolved method onOptionsItemSelected

Because  `onOptionsItemSelected` method is not available in `View` class. you can Override  `onOptionsItemSelected` method only when class is extending  `Activity`,`FragmentActivity` or classes which have `onOptionsItemSelected` method

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out a way to draw something one of the menu items is selected. Is there a good way do do this? I need access to some variable in the customview class

Comment: Since I need to redraw something on the canvas

Comment: @user3750474: create event listener using interface (for example [Android Custom Event Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881661/android-custom-event-listener)) to get values from Actvity to customview class when any menu items is selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
extends AppCompatActivity
```

in e.g.

```
public class MovieDetailView extends AppCompatActivity
```