# How to move from non activity class to activity class in android?

Tags: android

In my application it have three fragments. Every fragment have payment button, whenever we click the payment button one service will call. so for all fragments i wrote the service in non activity class. the service needs two variables from every fragment. so i send those variables to non activity class like this:

```
    fragment1:


 paymentbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Payment payment = new Payment(getActivity(),Mobilenumber,amount);
}

  fragment2:


    paymentbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     Payment payment = new Payment(getActivity(),Mobilenumber,amount);
        }

 fragment3:


 paymentbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Payment payment = new Payment(getActivity(),Mobilenumber,amount);
}




payment.java:

    public class Payment {
        JSONArray OrderItem;
        String mobNumber, amount;
        Context context;
        String payjson, jsontopayment;
        static Payment INSTANCE;

        public Payment(Context context, String mobNumber, String amount) {
            db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            INSTANCE = this;

            this.mobNumber = mobNumber;
            this.amount = amount;

            new GetPayment().execute(WebUrl.RechargeServiceURL + "AddRecharge");
        }

        public class GetPayment extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            /*String mJourneyDate;
            public GetData(String pJourneyDate) {
                this.mJourneyDate = pJourneyDate;
            }*/
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String response;

                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserUniqueID", "823166FC-83B5-4D7A-816BF81B6B0A5177"));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AccountNumber", mobNumber));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RCTypeID", rctypeid));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OperatorID", opid));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ServiceTypeID", srid));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CircleID", crid));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Amount", amount));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceID", "yeryer"));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                    HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

                    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                    // Log.d("response is", response);
                    return response;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                String Status;

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //Log.v("TAG_RESULT",""+result);

                if (result != null) {
                    try {
                        ////here i want to send the result to activty class
                        //result have json response`enter code here`
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        public String getJson() {
            payjson = OrderItem.toString();
            Log.v("test", "test");
            return payjson;
        }
    }

paymentActivty.java:

    public class Payment_Actiivity extends  Activity {
        Payment pay;
        String json;
        String str;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);
       // i need the json response in this class
        }
    }


i got the json response in non activty class. now i need to add this json data to another activity(payment_activity). so how i get my json response data to payment_activty. now my aim is whenever i click payment button in every fragment, it need to go payment_activity. please help me out.
```

Comment: [Android Custom Event Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881661/android-custom-event-listener) is useful to fix issue

Comment: sorry. i didnt get. i m new to java and andorid. please give some clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Broadcast to achieve what you want. Here is the code, have a try:

Add this method to the place where you want to send the result.

```
private void sendResult(String result){
    Intent intent = new Intent("yourpackage.result");
    intent.putExtra("my_result", result);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Add the following code to your Activity.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

// call this method in onCreate()
private void registerResultReceiver(){
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // here your get the result
            String result = intent.getStringExtra("my_result");
        }

    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("yourpackage.result");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

Add this line to the onDestroy() method of your Activity to unregister the receiver.

```
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Comment: sorry leog, yourpakage.result means,,,,?

Comment: It's the action of the Intent, use "your package name"  as it's prefix to keep its unique, eg. "com.google.result".

Comment: it is not working leog. i wrote log in sendresult. it is not printed

Comment: @Kartiki did you call the method sendResult() at the place "here i want to send the result to activty class"  in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: i am getting error ....@leog..i will tell my complete information. please help me out. I am trying from two days

Comment: In my application i want to execute one service for five times. so i want to write service in one non activity java class. this service require two variables from every fragment. so in every fragment i send those variables to this java class like this(  Payment payment = new Payment(getActivity(),Mobilenumber,amount);)  after that in this java class i execute the service and got json response. now i want make a custom listview for this json data in another activity(payment activty). so i need to change screen from every fragmnet to payment activty(middle i have payment.java)

Comment: @Kartiki Sorry, I don't understand, this seems another problem and it is not easy to understand if you write it simply in the comment , perhaps you can post another question.

Comment: please see my post now.

Answer (score 0):

make response string static global
public static Sting response;
add this line as like
response=new GetPayment().execute(WebUrl.RechargeServiceURL + "AddRecharge");

and parse that response string here like

```
            HttpEntity entity1 = (payment.respone).getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity1.getContent();
            r = convertStreamToString(stream);
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(r);
            s=  (Integer) jo.get("Flag");
            Log.d("json result is:", r);
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        Log.d("error", "code"+0);
    }
```

put converttostream method in this actvity

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There Are multiple methods to do this, one of the best method is write your own interface.

```
public interface MyInterface{
     public void getResult(String result);
}
```

Now in your Payment class create a local variable of interface myInterface and initialize it by changing your constructor.

```
 private MyInterface myInterface;
 public  Payment(Context  context,String mobNumber,String amount,MyInterface interface){
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        INSTANCE=this;

        this.mobNumber = mobNumber;

    this.amount = amount;
    this.myInterface=myInterface

    new GetPayment().execute(WebUrl.RechargeServiceURL + "AddRecharge");
}
```

And call that method like this way in onPostExecute()

```
 if (result != null) {
      try {
              myInterface.getResult(result);      
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
 } else {
      Toast.makeText(context, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
 }
```

Now in Your Activity just implement this interface and getResult() method.

EDIT:

Now it is more easy for you. Just implement MyInterface in all fragment.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements MyInterface{

    //Implemented method
    public void getResult(String result){
        //access your result from here
    }
}
```

Comment: please see my post now.

Comment: sorry. where i wrote this                                                                       public interface MyInterface{
     public void getResult(String result);
} and if i add MyInterface interface this constructor then how i change in every fragment

Comment: Payment payment = new Payment(getActivity(),Mobilenumber,amount);

Comment: as the constructor want a reference of an interface we must have to pass like this as 4th parameter.
Payment payment = new Payment(getActivity(),Mobilenumber,amount,Fragment1.this);

Comment: ok and how i get this json data from this non activty java class to activty class, whenerver i click the button in paybutton in every fragment,, for that i will wrote intent in paybutton of fragment. am i right?

Comment: I guess you are not aware about interface and callbacks, just read that and implement this solution, if you get any problem afterwords just post here.